# there is something wrong with my query and i dont know what is it?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the problem statement : Find the countries that have lost all their ships in battles.

The database description is : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T7D8.png)
Short database description "Ships"

The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database consists of the following relations:

```
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
Ships(name, class, launched)
Battles(name, date)
Outcomes(ship, battle, result)
```

Ships in classes all have the same general design. A class is normally assigned either the name of the first ship built according to the corresponding design, or a name that is different from any ship name in the database. The ship whose name is assigned to a class is called a lead ship.

The Classes relation includes the name of the class, type (can be either bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country the ship was built in, the number of main guns, gun caliber (bore diameter in inches), and displacement (weight in tons).

The Ships relation holds information about the ship name, the name of its corresponding class, and the year the ship was launched.

The Battles relation contains names and dates of battles the ships participated in.

The Outcomes relation - the battle result for a given ship (may be sunk, damaged, or OK, the last value meaning the ship survived the battle unharmed).

Notes:

1. The Outcomes relation may contain ships not present in the Ships relation.
2. A ship sunk can’t participate in later battles.
3. For historical reasons, lead ships are referred to as head ships in many exercises.
4. A ship found in the Outcomes table but not in the Ships table is still considered in the database. This is true even if it is sunk.

This is my code:

```
select country
from Classes left join Ships
on classes.class=ships.class
right join Outcomes
on Classes.class=ship
or ships.name=ship
where ship in (select ship from outcomes where result = 'sunk') 
group by country
;
```

my outcome is japan Germany and null the right outcome should be only germany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the trick is adding `and not exists (select 0 from ships where name = o.ship)` to your original query excluding the ships not present in the Ships table, and of course country column's value shouldn't be null since the related countries are asked. So consider using :

```
select country
  from Classes c
  left join Ships s
    on c.class = s.class 
 right join Outcomes o
    on c.class = ship
   and not exists (select 0 from ships where name = o.ship)
   and o.result = 'sunk'
 where c.country is not null
 group by country;
```

*btw, using `ship in (select ship from outcomes where result = 'sunk')` is redundant, `and o.result = 'sunk'` is enough.*

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `having` clause:

```
select c.country
from classes c join
     Ships s
     on c.class = s.class left join
     outcomes o
     on o.ship = s.name
group by c.country
having count(distinct s.name) = count(distinct case when o.result = 'sunk' then s.name end);
```

Comment: Doesn't give any outcome

Comment: @afbigdad . . . Are there any countries where all the ships were sunk?  Note:  there may be ships that never participated in a battle and they would not be sunk.

Answer (score 0):

I compared the ships per country against ships sunk per country, I filtered them to only show the countries with the same count in both tables

```
WITH ALL_SHIPS AS (
 SELECT ship, country from outcomes o
 JOIN classes c ON (c.class = o.ship)
 UNION
 SELECT name, country FROM ships s
 JOIN classes c ON (c.class = s.class)
),
SHIPS_PER_COUNTRY AS (
 SELECT country, COUNT(ship) count FROM ALL_SHIPS
 GROUP BY country
),
SHIPS_SUNK AS (
 SELECT ship, result FROM outcomes
 WHERE result = 'sunk'
),
SHIPS_SUNKED_PER_COUNTRY AS (
 SELECT aships.country, COUNT(ssunk.result) count FROM ALL_SHIPS aships
 JOIN SHIPS_SUNK ssunk ON (ssunk.ship = aships.ship)
 GROUP BY aships.country
)
SELECT spc.country FROM SHIPS_PER_COUNTRY spc
JOIN SHIPS_SUNKED_PER_COUNTRY sspc ON (sspc.country = spc.country)
WHERE spc.count = sspc.count
```